# Would Start a new activity after the progessbar reached 100%

Tags: android

I am facing a problem I  can't start a new activity after the progress bar reached 100% .This is my code I am get an error at startActivity.
Main.java
    package com.example.hprogressbarexmaple;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;


public class HProgressBarExmaple extends Activity {
protected static final int MAX_PROGRESS = 100;
protected static final long SLEEP_TIME = 200;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
ProgressBar myProgressBar;
int myProgress = 0;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    myProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.myProgress);
    new Thread(myThread).start();
}

private Runnable myThread = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // don't hard code things, use a constant for max progress value
        while (myProgress < MAX_PROGRESS) {
            try {
                myHandle.sendMessage(myHandle.obtainMessage());
                // same
                Thread.sleep(SLEEP_TIME);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                // never live an empty catch statement, you are missing
                // exceptions and
                // can't correct them
                Log.e("MyCurrentClass",
                        "Error during async data processing", ex);
            }// catch
        }// while
            // start new activity here
        startActivity(HProgressBarExmaple.this, List.class);
    }// met

    Handler myHandle = new Handler() {

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            myProgress++;
            myProgressBar.setProgress(myProgress);
        }
    };
};
}
```

I searched alot but I can't get a solution. Please help me and correct me if I am going wrong .

Comment: Post your error's stack trace please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(HProgressBarExmaple.this,List.class);
HProgressBarExmaple.this.startActivity(intent);
```

And do not forget to add `List Activity` in your `manifest.xml`

Comment: Thanks man it worked . Can u xplain me why I have to do like that . and I will up vote ur answer as soon as stackoverflow allows me to do that.

Comment: @user3270582 it's becoz  you can start a new instance of an `Activity` by passing an `Intent` to `startActivity()`. The `Intent` describes the activity to start and carries any necessary data. and for more information go to [http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html)